# Launching application from a database

Tags: delphi

I have many users using my application. However if I do some update, which I put on the server, not all of them are willing to update it (they sometimes afraid of changes they do not want to accustom).

So I speculate, how to force them to launch the latest application. There are surely several ways how to do it, but I have heard, that it is possible to launch an application stored in a blob field of a database.

Does anybody knows how it can be accomplished? (I am using MySQL database)

thanx

Answer (score 6):

Without judging on meaningful or nonsense ....
You could use [uExecFromMem](https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicssnippets/uexecfrommembysteve10120-fixedforwin7x64bytestest) .....
There is a Memoryleak in this unit which can be fixed by adding:

```
  ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
  Result := PI.hThread;
  FreeMem(pFile);  // added here
end;
```

an example call using a TBlobField would be

```
var
 ms:TMemoryStream;
begin
    ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
    TBlobField(YouDBBlobField).SaveToStream(ms);
    ms.Position := 0;
    ExecuteFromMem(Application.ExeName,'',ms.Memory); // pointing to an existing executable
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Why copy the `TMemoryStream` into a separate byte array, instead of passing `ms.Memory` to `ExecuteFromMem()` instead? By copying the data, you are duplicating the executable in memory, which is wasteful.

Comment: Also, `ExecuteFromMem()` works by starting a new process for `ExistingDummy.exe` in a suspended state, overwrites its memory with the input data, and then resumes the process. I don't think that is going to play very well with UAC and DEP technologies, especially UAC, which is only invoked at process creation time. The safest option would be to simply write the `TMemoryStream` data to a temporary `.exe` file and then execute it normally instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with you in both points. I had never need for such a requirement. So far I could not detect problems with UAC and DEP. I tried just for interest (proof of concept).

Comment: @bummi How to use unit in XE4.. Also is it 64 bit compatible?

Comment: @user2665920 I would not expectgetting it to work with 64bit. As mentioned in the comments above I just tried it for interest, maybe Remy's commment `... write the TMemoryStream data to a temporary .exe file and then execute it normally instead` will be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to use libraries.

You can have a small main executable file (some kind of "launcher"), which won't do nothing but launch external `.dll` fields. Just like a *kernel* does load modules at runtime (think about how Windows or Linux work).

Then you download an updated version of a `.dll`, stop and unload the old one, then load and initialize the new version.

Of course, your code has to be "clean", with proper startup and shutdown functions for each `.dll`.

But I suspect it would be much less error prone than `ExecuteFromMem()`. In this respect, good old load + execute of an `.exe` file (as *Remy* suggested) sounds like a much better option to me.

Comment: +1 this solution is much more cleaner and most likely work beyond windows 9